# Do numerical integration methods ever utilize evaluations of the derivative of the function?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximate-integration

Suppose one is performing numerical integration of some function $f(x)$, but in addition to being able to evaluate its value at points $f(x_1), \dots, f(x_n)$, one also can additionally obtain its derivative at those points for free $f'(x_1), \dots, f'(x_n)$. Are there numerical integration methods which are able to utilize the derivative values? If so, do such methods lead to improved order of accuracy?

Comment: I think that every method use to integrate differential equations would count.

Comment: @whpowell96 -- could you expand on this please? Runge-Kutta methods would still only use $f$, not $f'$.

Comment: The $f$ in the RHS of an ODE *is* a derivative. To integrate an ODE of the form $y' = f(t,y)$, one takes values of $y$, uses them to compute $y'$ exactly, then uses those to compute more values of $y$.

Comment: Actually I see the confusion now. I suppose that a numerical method used to integrate a second-order system would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I take it that you mean to address simple quadrature, not ODE integration.

One step in the derivation of Gauß quadrature is the discussing of the general quadrature based on Hermite interpolation. In Gauß quadrature, the nodes are selected so that the quadrature weights or coefficients of the derivative values are zero.

So if the nodes are in some other configuration, the quadrature method will have non-trivial contributions from the derivative values and the same order $2s$ for $s$ nodes with function and derivative values.

Comment: Could you provide some details or link to the relation of Gauss quadrature based on Hermite interpolation?

Comment: The question where I saw this last is unfortunately, but with reason, deleted. The book cited there is  Ralston/Rabinowitz (1978): *"A first course in numerical analysis"*. But it should be a standard topic in textbooks on numerical analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I think derivatives don't necessarily help. Take the single point Gauss-Laguerre rule $\int_0^\infty\,e^{-x}f(x)\, dx \approx w_1f(x_1)$, where $w_1 = 1$, $x_1 = 1$. This is exact for $f(x) = 1, x$. A different rule, in which the derivative is included,
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty\,e^{-x}f(x)\, dx \approx Af(\xi) + Bf'(\xi)
\end{equation}
would presumably be more accurate, say exact also for $x^2$, if $A$, $B$, and $\xi$ satisfied
\begin{align*}
1 &= A,\\
1 &= A\xi + B , \\
2 &= A\xi^2 + 2B\xi,
\end{align*}
corresponding to exactness for $f(x) = 1, x, x^2$. A bit of algebra shows this would require $\xi^2 - 2\xi + 2 = 0$, which doesn't have real roots, so this simple extension doesn't exist, at least in the sense described.